# Jquery explode on image that causes form to appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

I'm doing an Easter campaign for a company and I'm trying to add some nice animation. Here's the jist of it:

- Page starts off with an image of an egg rumbling using jrumble plugin on hover (got that part working)
- Then on clicking the egg image, it explodes and disappears
- instantly after I'd like a form to fade in.

I'm no JS wizz so I'm not sure how this sequence will work with the code, I have the right explode method in place but I'm clearly missing something as it's not working.

The form appearance is where I'm struggling, I'm not sure how to write it for it to appear.

My guess is using .click .explode on #egg and then toggle visibility of the form as the egg is clicked, but then it doesn't exactly fade in.

I'm aware this is vague but I'd really appreciate the help, I've added a code snippet to help.

Code is also on jsfiddle to tweak but jRumble isn't working on their for some reason.

https://jsfiddle.net/d851fdvk/6/

```js
$(function(){
    $('#egg').jrumble({
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    rotation: 4,
    speed: 150
    });
    
    $('#egg').hover(function(){
        $(this).trigger('startRumble');
    }, function(){
        $(this).trigger('stopRumble');
    }); 

    $('#egg').click(function() {
      $(this).hide('explode', {pieces: 16 }, 2000);
    });
    
    $('#egg').click(function() {
      $('.form').fadeIn( "slow" );
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.78thkingswood.co.uk/js/jquery.jrumble.1.3.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
    <p>Crack the egg to see what happens...</p>
    <img id="egg" src="http://abali.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/korichnevoe_yajco.png" Alt="Crack the egg!" />
    
    <form id="form-appear" style="display: none;" role="form">
        <div class="form-group required">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Name" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group required">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required="required">
        </div>      
        <div class="form-group required">
            <label for="inputPhone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" name="inputPhone" placeholder="Phone" required="required">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `.hide('explode')` ? Is this part of jRumble plugin?

Comment: No, that's a simple jquery effect. https://api.jqueryui.com/explode-effect/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't react on click. Nothing's moving... If you just want to make the form fade in, why not just `$("#form-appear").fadeIn()` ?

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that one (explode)

Comment: I know, that's what I can't figure out, why isn't it reacting?

Comment: I thought the code was fine but obviously not, is there syntax i'm missing? Look at the stack overflow snippet, the jquery is working but click explode does not

Comment: Well I can say for the fiddle now. It's a jQueryUI effect, but jQueryUI isn't included in the fiddle's dependencies. Or even jQuery at all. Obviously it can't work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the solution is : include jqueryUI (which is additional to jQuery). You're using jqueryUI's effects, but not including it in your dependencies.

Comment: My god how annoying, cheers mate. I didn't realise I needed to load the UI. 

It all works perfectly now.

Comment: Haha, it happened to the best of us =)

Answer (score 0):

chnage this part

```
  $('#egg').click(function() {
      $(this).hide('explode', {pieces: 16 }, 2000);
    });
```

To This

```
  $('#egg').click(function() {
      $(this).hide('explode', {pieces: 16 }, 2000,function(){
                                           $('#form-appear').fadeIn(slow); 
        });
    });
```

it's a callback function that will run after the click event.

Also The explode is part of the jquery Ui library and you havent included it.

Comment: This is the problem, the code looks good, but nothing is happening on click. 

I've even removed the other lines of code just to see if this works, still nothing. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Cheers for the callback function Chris

Answer (score 0):

it may be..

you need to initiation jquery-ui javaScript library in head of document to use "explode" method. it's not enough only jquery library for that.
 https://api.jqueryui.com/explode-effect/